# group.query on empty index gives exceptions

Tags: apache, solr

when i issue a query on empty data its giving exception. how to resolve this error

The query issued as follows

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/kittu/select?q=*:*&group.query=Status_s:close&group=true
```

By running the above query on empty data then following exception is thrown

msg": "numHits must be > 0; please use TotalHitCountCollector if you just need the total hit count",

Comment: Which version of Solr is it? Could be a bug/edge condition.

Comment: I tried on solr 5.3.1 and latest release 7.3.1. Both are giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be a bug then. Or unexpected edge-condition specifically. If there is no way you can avoid it, you could create [a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SOLR/issues).

However, this feature is a legacy part of Solr. You may want to investigate if the more-recent [JSON facets module](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/json-facet-api.html) will give you what you want easier.